# Is there a way to send maps using java.net?

Tags: java, dictionary, io

I am trying to have a program send a `Map` in Java to a client. The server uses this code:

```
Object r=(Object)WorldHandler.world;
Object y=(Object)WorldHandler.troops;
out.println(r);
out.println(y);
```

where `WorldHandler.troops` is a `HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,Troop>>`, `WorldHandler.world` is a `HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,Block>>`, and `out` is the `serverSocket.accept()`. Then the client tries to receive it like this:

```
Object tMap=socketIn.readLine();
Map<Integer,Troop> j=new HashMap<Integer,Troop>();
j=(Map<Integer,Troop>)tMap;
```

I get the error:

> `java.lang.ClassCastException`: `java.lang.String` cannot be cast to `java.util.Map`

at the line where it says `j=(Map<Integer,Troop>)tMap;`. Am I doing this wrong, or is there a way to do it?

Comment: Eh? This code makes little to no sense. What is `s`? You cannot just `toString` the `Map` and then cast it back to a `Map`. This is like doing `Map myMap = (Map)"Some random string"`.

Comment: You can't expect Java to magically convert the `toString` representation of a `Map` (which is a purely informative message) to an actual `Map` object. You need to serialize and deserialize the `Map`, for example using [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and `ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: the readline function is generally a string, not an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get several things straight:

- How to communicate with the client.  Typically this can be http requests, emails, ftp and others.
- What to communicate to the client.  You need a way to map your object into a form that the communication form expects and that the software on the other end can understand.

This needs to be in place before you can proceed.

A way to get started is to map your object into a JSON string either by yourself or using a third party library, and then transport that to the client.  If this starting point is not good enough, you can then start discussing what needs to be better.